# Treating outerHTML as jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to create just 2 simple boxes and allowing uses to choose data from 1 box, which copies it to the second box. If there is already a same one on the second box, append some simple text behind.

It works basically when the item is not in the second box. However, when it is, I'm unable to append data to the text.

Here's a simple example.

https://jsfiddle.net/9mbgw20e/5/

```
<div id="inventory">
  <div class='item'>
    <span>Apple</span>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <span>Pear</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="selected">

</div>


// bring the items from inventory to selected
// if selected is found, add some text to the back of it

$('.item').on('click', function() {
  var h = $(this)[0].outerHTML;

  var found = false;
  var foundId = '';
  if ($('#selected').children().length < 1) {
    // if there's nothing selected, just straight add this
    return $('#selected').prepend(h);
  }

  $('#selected').children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('span').text() == $(h).find('span').text()) { // if there is already one in selected div
      console.log('Found duplicated.');
      found = true;
      foundId = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
    }
  });

  if (!found) {
    // if item is not in selected div, add
    $('#selected').prepend(h);
  } else {
    // if item is in selected div, add some text to it
    $(foundId).append('1, ');
  }
});
```

Clicking the first time works, but after clicking it the second time, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change foundID to this `foundId = $(this);`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mbgw20e/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method instead:

```
foundId = $(this).first();
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mbgw20e/6/).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the updated code was here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It is. The only thing that I changed is the line where `foundId` is assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any reason to add `first();` since I'm already iterating through each child nodes? Thank you!

Comment: Not at all. As you can see in my answer I didn't need to use first();